# How can I use a webcam for Motion capture?

Tags: motion-capture

I'm new to Blender so, for everything I want to do, I watch tutorials on YouTube.

I recently learnt I can do motion capture using my Webcam: this is a lot easier than setting keyframes, so I went to YouTube to search for tutorials on how to use Webcam for motion capture.

I found one and followed the steps throughout, but the problem I face is that I cannot change the location of my character: if I try to do so, the body part linked to the empty, set to copy movement from the video to the mesh, will remain at the same point while other body would move, causing some stretches in the mesh.

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Please share screenshots of what you are doing and/or a .blend file as well if you wish to get better answers.

Comment: to share a .blend, please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then edit your question, pasting the provided link.

Comment: From what I read, I'm guessing here that you're having the same problem you get when using hooks for shapekeys. Solution - make a parent empty for the body itself, then parent all the hooks to that as well.  (hooks & body=children) Move the empty about, not the body.